# boost asio ssl writing part of data

Tags: c++, boost, openssl, boost-asio

My client-server app, that communicating through boost asio, usign functions:

When connection starts, client send to server bunch of requests, server send back some response.
After adding *asio::ssl* to project i get following problem.

Sometimes, 1/5 times, server reads only first fixed part of requests. When client disconnected, server get all missed requests.

On client side all seems good, callbakcs called with no errors and writed sizes are proper. But result from packet sniffer show that ***client not sending*** this part of requests.

Client :

Size of each "frame" located in header, first must read atleast header.
Thread Worker used for background work, and pushing ready packets to storage.

```
using SSLSocket = boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>;


class AsyncStrategy :
    public NetworkStrategy
{
    // other data...

    void _WriteHandler(const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t bytes);

    bool Connect(const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint);

    void _BindMessage();
    void _BindMessageRemainder(size_t size);
    void _AcceptMessage(const boost::system::error_code& err_code, size_t bytes);
    void _AcceptMessageRemainder(const boost::system::error_code& err_code, size_t bytes);

    // to keep io_service running
    void _BindTimer();
    void _DumpTimer(const boost::system::error_code& error);

    void _SolveProblem(const boost::system::error_code& err_code);

    void _Disconnect();

    bool verify_certificate(bool preverified,
        boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx);

    PacketQuery query;

    boost::array <Byte, PacketMaxSize> WriteBuff;
    boost::array <Byte, PacketMaxSize> ReadBuff;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep;
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer _Timer{ service };
    boost::asio::ssl::context _SSLContext;
    SSLSocket sock;

    boost::thread Worker;

    bool _ThreadWorking;
    bool _Connected = false;
};


AsyncStrategy::AsyncStrategy( MessengerAPI& api)
        : API{api},_SSLContext{service,boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23 },
                sock{ service,_SSLContext }, _Timer{service},
                    Worker{ [&]() {
                                _BindTimer();
                                service.run();
                        } },  
                _ThreadWorking{ true }
{
    _SSLContext.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
    _SSLContext.set_verify_callback(
        boost::bind(&AsyncStrategy::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

    _SSLContext.load_verify_file("ca.pem");
}


bool AsyncStrategy::verify_certificate(bool preverified,
    boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
{
    return preverified;
}

void AsyncStrategy::_BindMessage()
{
    boost::asio::async_read(sock, buffer(ReadBuff,BaseHeader::HeaderSize()),
            boost::bind(&AsyncStrategy::_AcceptMessage, this, _1, _2));
}

bool AsyncStrategy::Connect(const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
{
    ep = endpoint;

    boost::system::error_code err;
    sock.lowest_layer().connect(ep, err);

    if (err)
        throw __ConnectionRefused{};

    // need blocking handshake
    sock.handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client, err);

    if (err)
        throw __ConnectionRefused{};

    _BindMessage();
    return true;
}


void AsyncStrategy::_AcceptMessage(const boost::system::error_code& err_code, size_t bytes)
{
     // checking header, to see, packet ends or not
     // if there is more data in packet, read rest my binding function
    // pseudocode
    if( need_load_more )
        _BindMessageRemainder(BytesToReceive(FrameSize));
        return;
    }
    // if not use this bind this function next time
    _CheckPacket(ReadBuff.c_array(), bytes);
    _BindMessage();
}

void AsyncStrategy::_AcceptMessageRemainder(const boost::system::error_code& err_code, size_t bytes)
{
    if (err_code)
    {
        _SolveProblem(err_code);
        return;
    }
    _CheckPacket(ReadBuff.c_array(), bytes + BaseHeader::HeaderSize()); 
    _BindMessage();
}

bool AsyncStrategy::Send(const TransferredData& Data)
{
    // alreay known, that that data fits in buffer
    Data.ToBuffer(WriteBuff.c_array()); 
    boost::asio::async_write(sock,
            buffer(WriteBuff, Data.NeededSize()),
            boost::bind(&AsyncStrategy::_WriteHandler, this, _1, _2));

    return true;
}

void AsyncStrategy::_WriteHandler(const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t bytes)
{  
    if (err)
        _SolveProblem(err);
}
```

After removing all ssl stuff, data transfer is normal. As i mentioned, all works properly before ssl integration.

Finding solution, i discovered that if send with delay, tried 200 ms, all data transferring normally.

Win10, boost 1.60, OpenSSL 1.0.2n

I guess there may be an error in my code, but I tried almost everything I thought. Looking for advice.

Comment: Maybe you interleave requests or something... It's hardly possible to guess what the reason is, without seeing your code. If cannot make sscce, at least post the relevant snippets. (BTW, if you only change your socket to the regular, non-ssl one, does everything work?)

Comment: Names starting with `__` are reserved. Your program may have unspecified behaviour because of it. Global/namespace level names starting with a single `_` are also _verboten_

Comment: @sehe replaced all symbols staring with _ and __ , problem still remain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't see how `Send` is actually called.

Perhaps it needs to be synchronized.

We **can** that it reuses the same buffer each time, so two writes overlapping will clobber that buffer.

We **can** also see that you're not verifying that the size of the `Data` argument fits into the `PacketMaxSize` buffer.

This means you  will not only lose data if you exceed the expected buffer size, it will also invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: data, fits in buffer, checked before send. I thought that is TCP s duty to synchronize writes

Comment: Yes. Assuming that you write the correct data to the socket, synchronously. With async communications you are responsible for keeping the buffer valid until the async predation completes

Comment: i perform send only from single thread, and there is separate buffer for reading, it should be enough

Comment: if i understand correnctly, ist asio task to keep buffer valid. As i saw, inside async_write finction, data copied to other buffer

Comment: Oops. No you misunderstood. In fact, you couldn't be more wrong: It's **never** Asio's responsibility to keep buffers valid. That's one of the design pillars in Asio, which gives maximum power to its users: it is up to the user to decide whether you want to pay the price of copying buffers for simplicity. But you "don't pay for what you don't use"

Comment: what exactly i should do to fix this?

Comment: Re: "I perform send only from a single thread" - that's not enough to guarantee no overlapping operations! Asynchrony is simply _another way_ to achieve parallel execution without concurrency (at the same level; there will be hardware, kernel concurrency e.g.). This simplistic example shows how it is obviously a problem: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fXm7y6qWB4/ - there's only one thread involved, but clearly you're overwriting `msg` before (you know) it had been transmitted.

Comment: @VitaliyLutsushyn Re: "what _exactly_ should I do to fix this" - it's hard for me to say. Your sample code is very involved and uses all kinds of hard-to-grasp utilities that nobody knows (`TransferredData::ToBuffer(...) const`? `BytesToReceive(FrameSize`? `_BindMessageRemainder`? etc.). I'd say you should probably start with a much simpler, isolated piece of code, and possibly invite a code review on [CodeReview.SE] before proceeding on integrating it into your codebase in such elaborate ways. I know that's painful, but the fact is you probably jumped in a bit too soon.

Comment: PS. In case it is of any help this is what I had created yesterday in an effort to understand/compile your sample: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8TKx32gK2b/ but I stopped when it became clear I wouldn't be able to grok it completely or make it self-contained.

Comment: I used another network library in project, but dont i dont get important things in asio, now im understand my faults. Thanks a lot!